# Generate unjoined extra line for View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I'm sorry i really have no idea what keywords to use to find help for my problem.

I'm building a View on SQL to use in an other Software which has filter capabilities on its own. I want to use the view for several purposes, so i have some kind of an unorthodx idea:

Originally, I wanted to LEFT OUTER JOIN two tables. But: even if the SQL finds a match, i want an extra record  that doesn't have data from the Right table anyway. Here is an example:

t1:

```
pk   data
1    a
2    b
3    c
```

t2:

```
pk  fk  data
1    a   line1
2    a   line2
3    c   line3
4    c   line4
5    c   line5
```

here is what i currently get:
query:

```
select t1.data, t2.data from t1 left outer join t2 on t1.data = t2.fk
```

return:

```
t1.data  t2.data
a        line1
a        line2
b        <NULL>
c        line3
c        line4
c        line5
```

what i actually want to return:

```
t1.data  t2.data
a        <NULL>
a        line1
a        line2
b        <NULL>
c        <NULL>
c        line3
c        line4
c        line5
```

The reason i want to have this result is that i can use the View in the other software and filter just for the records with t2.data = NULL

does anyone know how i can do this? I don't want to manually join in the software because its performance inefficient to a degree thats not bareable for the enduser.

your help is appreciated.

P.S. I thought about replacing the right table with a subselect that full outer joins a non-matching top(1) selection but i can't figure out how to do that properly :-/

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is this:  Use an `INNER JOIN` so you don't get the records with NULL, and then use a UNION on t1 forcing the NULL t2.data column.

```
SELECT t1.data, t2.data
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.data = t2.fk
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.data, NULL
FROM t1
```

This should get you the resultset you want.

Comment: thank you, I will look further into the union command. Unfortunatly my view is too complex to just test it right now. (2 joined tables, 2 additional subselects joining 3 more tables added by outer applies - i'll try to figure the implementation out on my own)

Comment: Thx again, it worked.. didn't expect the solution to be so simple :]